# cp command not copying all of large file when run from a shell script

Tags: 14.04

I have a strange issue that makes no sense, at least not to me.
Any help is appreciated.

This method only copies about 1GB of the 1.4GB file

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /home/buildskel/large1.4gbfile $HOME
```

This method, "not running in a script" copies the complete file

```
cp /home/buildskel/large1.4gbfile $HOME
```

Comment: What command are you using to call the script? Do you receive any error message or other output from the script? Is the problem reproducible--that is, have you tried each way multiple times and verified the script always copies only ~1 GB while running `cp` manually as a single command always copies the whole thing? Is the script you've shown us literally what you are running, or does your script have other lines also? What's the output of `echo $?`, run immediately after executing your script? What is it when run after running the `cp` command manually? (Please [edit] with this info--thanks!)

Comment: the script is +x so ./scriptname. Yes the script posted is all there is to it. If I use dd which bypasses the file cache it gets the whole file.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem except my file is 87GB, copied from bash and it only ever copies ~55GB.